# Facebook:How can I always post a photo to the wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get the photo to appear in the user's feed, but only the first photo. Uploading successive photos after that still adds the photo to the album named as my app, but it doesn't seem to do anything else to the feed.

```
NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=%@",self.fbAccessToken]]; 
self.fbRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl];
[self.fbRequest  setTimeOutSeconds:60];
self.fbRequest .uploadProgressDelegate = self;
self.fbRequest .delegate = self;
self.fbRequest .requestMethod = @"POST";
[self.fbRequest  setPostValue:[item customValueForKey:@"status"]  forKey:@"message"];
[self.fbRequest  addData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(item.image) forKey:@"source"];
self.fbRequest.tag = RequestStepUpload;
[self.fbRequest  startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: That's just how it works, why do you want a different feed story for each photo? o_O

Comment: it's not me.The customer of my app want a different feed story for each photo.

Comment: That's not possible - they should attach images to feed posts if they need each one displayed separately

Answer (score 1):

hi you have to post a image on  facebook then please refer this tutorial. 
we are working with this code and it is working very well in iphone and ipad.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/

Thanks.

Comment: Thx，but I know how to post a image on facebook. The point is when I posted a image,I need it always appear in the user's feed.